# Proof of concept loading php files via javascript

Tags: javascript, php, include, onload

Here's what I know:
PHP is server side and js is client side.
I can't use Js to change a PHP variable because of what I wrote in the line above BUT
onLoad can i include a file or an another if (as an example) page is loaded inside an iFrame? (yeah my server allows x-frame SAMEORIGIN) I also know that I can't use get_stylesheet_directory_uri() to set the url of this file.

I know that I can use:

```
<script>
    if (window.frameElement) {
        // in frame
    }
    else {
        // not in frame
    }
</script>
```

To check if my page is loaded in an iFrame but then I am like Jon Snow, I know nothing.

I've also read that using this:

```
function my_enqueue_assets() {
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-pagination', 'ajaxpagination', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    ));
}
```

I can somehow have a way to 'navigate' trough my folders, am I right?
How to pack everything for the inclusion?
Thank you.

Now to try to explain more what I would like to achieve here is some 'pseudo code' (I know that I mixed js and PHP and it can't work like this).

```
<script>
if (window.frameElement) {
    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/header/iframe','page');?>
}
else {
    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/header/notiframe','page');?>
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to use javascript to check if page is loaded inside an iFrame.
If it is in iFrame it has to include  a php file,
if it's not it has to include a different one.

<script>
    if (window.frameElement) {
        // in frame
<?php get_template_part('template-parts/header/site','branding');?>
    }
    else {
        // not in frame
<?php get_template_part('template-parts/header/header','navbar');?>
    }
</script>

Comment: detect with js, make an ajax call to the php file, will work depending on what the php file does

Comment: Actually i've solved my problem with a workaround, without using JS. 
What have I to do? Have I to delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, without using js I managed to solve the problem.
Where i create the permalinks I've added this:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'access_method', 'iframe', get_permalink() ) );?>" class="iframe" title="<?php the_title();?>"">
```

Then on top of the pages I set a variable:

```
<?php $iframechecker = ( isset($_GET["access_method"]) && trim($_GET["access_method"]) == 'iframe' ) ?true : false;?>
```

Then I check if it is set:

```
<?php if (($iframechecker === true)){;?>//do stuff<?php }else{;?>//do other stuff<?php };?>
```

Hope this will help someone in the future.